# Set multi header, frozen column and fixed header with jquery datatables

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

i have some question about jquery datatables here.

my table is using multi header and the 4 first column is to be set frozen.

i've 25 column in total, here's is the example of my table:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="tabel_daftar_all" align="center" style="text-align: center;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <!--<th rowspan="4">No</th>-->
                <th rowspan="4">Categories1</th>
                <th colspan="3">Categories2</th>
                <th colspan="14">Categories3</th>
                <th colspan="5">Categories4</th>
                <th rowspan="4">Remark</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="3">X</th>
                <th rowspan="3">X 1</th>
                <th rowspan="3">X 2</th>
                <th colspan="3">X</th>
                <th rowspan="3">X</th>
                <th colspan="3">X</th>
                <th rowspan="3">X</th>
                <th colspan="6">X</th>
                <th colspan="2">X</th>
                <th rowspan="2">X</th>
                <th rowspan="2">X</th>
                <th rowspan="2">X</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <th rowspan="2">X</th>
                <th rowspan="2">X</th>
                <th rowspan="2">X</th>
                <th rowspan="2">X</th>
                <th rowspan="2">X</th>
                <th rowspan="2">X</th>
                <th rowspan="2">X</th>
                <th rowspan="2">X</th>
                <th>X</th>
                <th>X</th>
                <th colspan="2">X</th>
                <th>X</th>
                <th>X</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th>Y/N</th>
                <th>X</th>
                <th>X</th>
                <th>X</th>
                <th>X</th>
                <th>X</th>
                <th>X</th>
                <th>X</th>
                <th>X</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <!--PHP select from database-->
        </tbody>
</table>
```

when i'am trying to set just 1 column, it was a success,

however when i changes it to 4, i got some problems,

why the style of top header with multi rows header on frozen column seems to be different,

here is the screenshot:
[image: screenshot 1]

beside that, on firefox, the rows seems to be rigged too

screenshot:
[image: rigged]

not only that, i want to use the fixed header too, but it seems unsupported on scrolling mode,
is there any solution for that too?

as for the script of my datatables is here:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready( function () {

//Auto column resize for datatable inside tab
    $("#kontenTab").tabs( {
        "show": function(event, ui) {
            var oTable = $('div.dataTables_scrollBody>table.display', ui.panel).dataTable();
            if ( oTable.length > 0 ) {
                oTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
            }
        }
    } );

    var oTable = $('#tabel_daftar_all').dataTable( {
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "bSort": false,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "sScrollX": "100%",
        //"sScrollXInner": "150%",
        "bScrollCollapse": true,
        "bFilter": false
    } );    

    new FixedColumns( oTable, {
        "iLeftColumns": 4
    } );

    //new FixedHeader( oTable );
} );
</script>
<style>
table.display thead th {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 3px 18px 3px 10px;
}
</style>
```

sorry if i ask too much,

i hope anyone can help me solve this problems XD